# Gram determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How to prove that

$$\sqrt{\Gamma(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})}=|(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})|,$$

where $\Gamma(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})= \left | \begin{array} {ccc} \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} & \vec{b} \cdot \vec{a} & \vec{c} \cdot \vec{a} \\
\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} & \vec{b} \cdot \vec{b} & \vec{c} \cdot \vec{b} \\
\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} & \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} & \vec{c} \cdot \vec{c}
\end{array} \right | $.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $(\vec a,\vec b,\vec c)$?

Comment: I always disliked the use of vertical bars to denote the determinant: too subtle and overloaded. As user1551 pointed out, you need the modulus of the determinant on the right. So maybe a more transparent way to write the problem would be $\sqrt{\Gamma(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})}=|\det(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the matrix $X$ have rows $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec c$.

Then $XX^T$ is the matrix within the vertical bars in your definition of the gram determinant.

Then you have $\Gamma(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})=\det(XX^T)=\det(X)\det(X^T)=\dots$

Can you take it from here?

---

If in fact you do want to work with complex vectors, then I need to alter the above slightly. To be consistent with the order of terms in the dot products, you would have ot use *column* vectors instead of row vectors, and the Hermitian conjugate instead of the transpose. You'd also need the fact that the determinant of $X^H$ is the complex conjugate of the determinant of $X$, and multiplying them would give you the square modulus of the determinant of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $\vec{a}$ and the like are column vectors. Your $\Gamma$ is just the matrix product $A^\ast A$, where $A=(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})$ and $A^\ast$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$ (or simply the transpose of $A$ if $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are real). Using the properties that $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$ and $\det(X^\ast)=\overline{\det(X)}$, we see that $\det(\Gamma)=\overline{\det(A)}\det(A)=|\det(A)|^2$ and hence the correct statement should be:
$$\sqrt{\det(\Gamma)}=|\det(A)|,$$
where the pair of strokes $|\cdot|$ here denotes the modulus of a complex number (or absolute value of a real number). Without taking the modulus, your statement is wrong. A counterexample is given by $\vec{a}=(-1,0,0)^\top,\ \vec{b}=(0,-1,0)^\top$ and $\vec{c}=(0,0,-1)^\top$.